# How to use a method of an object stored in a TList?

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

My question is pretty simple. I have a TList (called `queue`) containing objects of class `CNotif` and want to use the method `is_alive` on those objects.

The problem is, when I use `queue.Items[0].is_alive()`, I get an error message saying `Error: Illegal qualifier`.

I'm also confused with the way I can instantiate objects in this TList (and how the way the compiler "knows" that the objects stored are of this type ...)

What I do now is: `queue.Add(CNotif.create(timer, title, text, badge))` but I don't think it's supposed to be done that way.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Just a sidenote. There is an unwritten convention to name the types with the first char `T`, like `TLama` is type of `Lama`, so for your case it would be `TCNotif` ;-)

Comment: Isn't it C for Classes and T for "basic" types (like an array or a record) ?

Comment: Nope, it's for all `T`ypes, including classes, records, enumerations etc. Let's say for everything you have in the `type` section of your code.

Comment: Just to clarify, as TLama points out, in your case it would actually be `TNotif` if I'm not mistaken - if the `C` was your prefix intended. But everything after the `T` is all up to you anyway, so technically there's no right or wrong way to name types. Things will still work without the `T` but in Delphi, types are expected to begin with `T`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The problem is, when I use queue.Items[0].is_alive(), I get an error message saying Error: Illegal qualifier.

That's because the compiler has no idea what `queue.items[0]` is other than a generic pointer (see below).

> What I do now is: queue.Add(CNotif.create(timer, title, text, badge)) but I don't think it's supposed to be done that way.

This is exactly the way you need to do it. `CNotif.Create` constructs a new object, and that object descends from `TObject`.
It compiles fine because your `queue.Add` call is expecting a pointer, and a Delphi/FreePascal variable containing an object instance is actually a pointer. (Both languages hide the need to dereference using `MyObj^` for us.)

To use something in `queue.Items`, you need to tell the compiler what's in there other than a generic `pointer` (which of course doesn't have an `is_alive` method). You do that by typecasting:

```
CNotif(queue.Items[0]).is_alive
```

Note: There's a shorter way to use the `TList.Items`; `Items` is declared as the default property for the `TList`, so you can omit it:

```
queue[0]
```

is the same as

```
queue.Items[0]
```

and is much easier to type.

Comment: Good point. :) My mistake; wrote too quickly and must have been thinking `TObjectList`. I'll correct it. Thanks. :)

Comment: Indeed, great explanation, +1

Answer (score 6):

Unless you're stuck with an old Delphi version, you should look into generics.

In the generics.collection unit there is a `TList<T>` class that you could use here.

```
Queue:TList<CNotify>;

...
Begin
  Queue := TList<CNotify>.Create; // remember to clean it up
  Queue.Add(CNotify.Create(...));
  Queue.Add(CNotify.Create(...));

  If Queue[0].isAlive then
    Beep;
End;
```

I haven't used fpc and lazarus for a while, but in Delphi this is definitely the way to do this. Lists of untyped pointers and type-casts all over the place can become a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: +1, but it might be good to mention from D2010+ because there were several problems in D2009 especially with `TList`.

Comment: In fpc ObjFPC mode, the syntax is `type TQueue = specialize TFPGList<CNotify>` -- but you can also use Delphi mode which has Delphi syntax (at least since 2.6).